# Is it possible to setup two different URL Schemas for two different builds(ex. Development and Production) in the same project in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, plist, build-process

I made two different schemas(two builds, e.g. Development and Production) in my iOS project.
And I have to provide a possibility when a user clicks on a link in a mail, to redirect him(if he has the app installed) to the app.

I've done a little research and I saw that I can do that with URL Schemas.
But I have not found a way how to set an URL Schema to the particular build(app), how to differentiate them.

Is there a way to set two different URL Schemas for two different builds in the same app?

Comment: If the two different builds have the same bundle ID then only one can be installed on a given device at a time, so you can just use the same URL scheme - The app that is installed will be open.  If they have different Bundle IDs then they are different apps and have different Info.plist files, so you can specify different URL schemes.  You can also declare multiple URL schemes for the one app in your Info.plist and then check when the URL is received which was used and process them differently.

Comment: They have different bundle ID, but I have only one info.plist file, because I was using   User Defined Settings to differentiate the bundleIDs and other configurations which differ and make builds. And because I have only one info.plist i don't know how to setup the URL schema for both of builds. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy info plist just to make a small change. Create an xcconfig file to define the values that are different for the two schemes and just reference that in your info.plist

This way the guy who recently joined the project can't forget to add a value to both plists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Copy your original `Info.plist` and name it for example `Info_debug.plist`

Then click on your project (the blue icon at the very top left of your file navigator) and go in the Build Settings > Packaging section, there you will find the item "Info.plist file" and if you made at least 2 different builds you should get a little arrow right to the left of this item: unfold it and you should be able to customize your plist file for every build... As shown on the attached screenshot.

In this example you should just change the name of the Debug line to `Info_debug.plist` and you're done!

[image: Xcode 11 interface showing the emplacement of the info.plist file path depending on the build setting]

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. :) I wasn't shure if that would somehow mess up my configuration. Thank you again.

Comment: If you wander around into those Build Settings you will find a lot of items that are build-profile-dependent... this allows to customize quite much every build :)